# How to Reset the dropdown values on form submission, Other Input values are getting Cleared in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form and when I click on submit button, the data gets submitted to server.
Now, After the data got submitted to server, I Need to clear the Form data to empty.
Every fields gets clear other than Dropdown value.What was Issue Here??

```
const Form = () => {
        const [data, setdata] = useState({
            "UserName" : "",
            "PhoneNumber" : "",
             "email" : "",
              "dropDown" :"",
        })
    
        const [update, setUpdate] = useState([])
    
        const handleChange =(e)=>{
         setdata({...data,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
            
        }
    
       const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        // setUpdate({...data,update});
        // console.log(data);
          axios.post('url',data).then((res)=>{
            //   console.log("user added successfully");
            handleClear();      
          })
    
       }
```

So, here I wrote the function to clear the form and I  called that function after the submitting the form

```
 const handleClear=()=>{
        let clear={
            "UserName" : "",
            "PhoneNumber" : "",
             "email" : "",
              "dropDown" :"",
        }
        setdata(clear);
    }
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>LordShiva</h1>
                <div className="container mt-3">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-header bg-success text-white">
                                    <h4>Form</h4>
                                    <form>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='UserName' name="UserName" value={data.UserName} onChange={handleChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input name="phone" className="form-control" placeholder='PhoneNumber' name="PhoneNumber" value={data.PhoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        {/* <div className="form-group">
                                                       <DatePicker selected={startDate} placeholder='Select Date' />
                                                       </div> */}
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input name="email" className="form-control" placeholder='Email' value={data.email} onChange={handleChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <select name="dropDown" onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" >
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="Reactjs">ReactJS</option>
                                                <option value="JS">JavaScript</option>
                                                <option value="csCSSs">CSS</option>
                                                <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                       

                                            <div className="form-row">
                                            <button className="btn btn-cyan" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment >
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `dropdown` state value to the `value` prop of the `select` element.

```
<select
  name="dropDown"
  value={data.dropdown} // <-- set value to make a controlled input
  onChange={handleChange}
  className="form-control"
>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Reactjs">ReactJS</option>
  <option value="JS">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="csCSSs">CSS</option>
  <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes It working, Thanks a lot, But I am having Radio and checkboxes also, But I havn't passed a value prop to the  Radio and checkboxes and its gets cleared, But only dropdown was not cleared.. Is there any Specific reason for that?

Comment: @Sundeep Nothing off the top of my head, but I wouldn't think they'd behave any differently than other inputs. Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: No reproducible example, I am just new to ReactJS , I am learning now and just Doing some examples. Thanks a lot for your help, Is there any Good videos or any Course to learn React Hooks?

Comment: @Sundeep IMO the react docs are pretty good. If you are jumping in to react hooks I would suggest making sure you are really comfortable with the react component lifecycle and state updates. This will help you understand when hook callbacks run and how the dependencies trigger them. I'd search for articles written by Dan Abromov if you wanted more resources.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will search on that

Comment: Can you look at this Issue once, Here is the link, please help me, tell me what I did wrong...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366115/unable-to-bind-the-radio-button-and-checkbox-data-on-button-click-in-react-hooks